# Function that returns first digit from a String

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that returns the first digit in a `String`, and if there isn't one then the function should return `1`.

Example:

`firstNumber "Example456"` should return `4` because that is the first digit in the `String`.

`firstNumber "Example"` should return `1` because there is no digit.

This is what I have so far:

```
firstNumber :: String -> Int
firstNumber = read . maximumBy (length) . map (isDigit)
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
headDef [] = 1
headDef (x:_) = read [x]
firstNumber = headDef. filter isDigit

s="Example456"
```

Output:

```
*Main> firstNumber s
4
*Main> firstNumber "ex"
1
*Main>
```

The function `headDef` tries to retrieve the first element of a list and replace it with a default value if the list is empty. You can change the default value/type in `headDef` to something else if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Returning `1` if no number is found isn't very good, what if the string contains the number `1` and that was the first one?  Instead, you could use the `Maybe` data type that represents either a failed computation with `Nothing` or a valid return value with `Just`.

You could do something like

```
firstNumber :: String -> Maybe Int
firstNumber s = fmap digitToInt $ listToMaybe $ filter isDigit
```

But you'll need `Data.Maybe` imported to get `listToMaybe`.  Then you can use it as

```
> firstNumber "example"
Nothing
> firstNumber "example456"
Just 4
```

---

If you did want to return `1` on a failed search then you could just do

```
firstNumberOr1 :: String -> Int
firstNumberOr1 = fromMaybe 1 . firstNumber
```

The `fromMaybe` function has the definition

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
fromMaybe default Nothing = default
fromMaybe default (Just a) = a
```

So `fromMaybe 1` will return `1` when given `Nothing`, and just unwrap whatever value was in the `Just` if given that.